# Would it be morally right to kill fiends by modern world standards?

Tags: worldbuilding-process, ethics, supernatural

Fiends in my story were usually were once human teenagers, but since then (usually voluntary) have gained power, immortality, and supernatural abilities by submitting themselves to The OtherWorld King. Fiends tend to be teenagers who come from bad homes, and agree to the offer from the OtherWorld King because he promises them these powers and better home. When a teenager becomes a fiend they tend to keep close to their human morals. But due to hanging out with other fiends, and losing their human side more and more over time (sometimes they completely forget their origins and name) they become more devilish and start to have no issues with hurting others. It's also important to remember that even after hundreds of years that they've stayed at that mental state the day they decided to become a fiend, so they never become much wiser or much smarter. So even though they do basically work for the Devil, would it still be morally wrong to kill one because mentally they are still teenagers?

Edit: Many fiends engage in petty crime, but sometimes can be responsible for arson, assault, and murder. But fiends are most infamous for the kidnapping of infants and young children and replacing them with children, and when fully grown are much smarter and more dangerous than fiends. So they really exist only to blend in (they can still transform into their former human form) and to build up the army.

Edit: If your answering this based on perspective/and or condition say your apart of the local law enforcement and you catch a fiend in the act of stealing jewelry. You know for a fact that fiends do indeed work for evil, but at the same time it's only engaging in a rather petty crime.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133878/discussion-on-question-by-wilbur-wummins-would-it-be-morally-right-to-kill-fiend).

Comment: "Other...king"  Is there a state of war, or the moral equivalent?

Comment: Ethics and law enforcement don't intersect at all. It isn't ethical to charge into a situation with a gun in hand ready to blow the perpetrator to kingdom come, but that doesn't stop them from rushing onto a in-progress crime with guns blazing, getting innocents killed in the process. No, it is not ethical, but the vast majority of law enforcement are going to DO IT ANYWAY.

Answer (score 7):

**They are not Teenagers.**

Proponents of executing Fiends will argue they are no longer teenagers.

The difference between a child an an adult is mental plasticity. Children are still developing. If a child does a bad thing then it is believed to be easier to reprogram that child to not do the bad thing again. Adults on the other hand are harder to reprogram and that removes an option for what to do with them. Then the other options of execution or imprisonment move one step up the queue.

This is one moral justification for why child and adult criminals should be treated differently.

Proponents of executing Fiends would argue this malleability is the defining feature of being a child. And because of that, once a teenager becomes a fiend, they are no longer a teenager. They are instead a different type of adult and should be treated as such.

This assumes un-fiending a teenager is relatively hard. If it can be reversed the above does not hold up. You just take the fiend, suck out the demon and reprogram lickety split.

If removing the demon is possible but difficult there is still an argument to be made for execution. It should be analogous to life imprisonment vs execution. The former is difficult in that it is expensive to imprison someone for very long. It can be argued the moral action is to execute the bad person and use the money to improve the quality of life of not bad persons. Likewise it might be more moral to use your time/money/effort to helping non-fiends than use it to suck out a demon.

Answer (score 4):

''mentally they are still teenagers....so they never become much wiser or much smarter.'' does this mean they are unable to learn and remember new things?

In this case they are just zombies, literal living memories, they are already dead. It isn't murder it's euthanasia, as morally right as ending the life of someone living in comatose.

If by ''mentally they are still teenagers'' you mean that their brains stop maturing, well male brains apparently mature in 2 stages, puberty then the final stage around the age of 17 to 24 years, for some men it is faster for other men it's slower. This stage exists to differentiate male brains from female brains since the human brain is genderless...I mean sexless at birth.

Is it morally right to murder individuals age 17 or younger in todays standards? Yes, in self defense and in war it is morally right to kill humans without it being considered murder, homicide or manslaughter.

Comment: -1 common misconception about use of a term... it would be *involuntary* euthanasia. Common term for that is murder, opener question is about moral dilemma's involving murder, not euthanasia.

Comment: @Goodies doubt someone in vegetative state can consent  to being killed, maybe it's a different definition by country, where I live euthanasia is NOT ASSISTED SUICIDE.

Comment: For your information, in countries where euthanasia is allowed it will NOT happen when there is no prior consent. A vegetative state is no reason for euthanasia as such. It can be decided on medical grounds there is suffering without perspective, but there has to be proof for that condition, and consent from family and/or friends. The term "Euthanasia" is *not* applicable to law enforcement action.

Comment: @Goodies and what exactly stops this defitnion of a third part consent from also happening with fiends? Families can consent to kill a braindead living carcass but can't consent to kill a braindead living carcas that has a different name "fiend" ?

Answer (score 4):

## Yes, as we do so to terrorists.

The devil is essentially a foreigner from another nation who is sending dangerous and weaponized individuals into other countries to cause terror.

The USA uses drones [to kill even USA citizens](https://www.bbc.com/news/av/world-22634614) who become terrorists, and if there was actually an organized foreign nation that purposely worked to abduct and kill children en masse, and was associated with being the prime evil of a huge number of religious organizations you'd expect an extremely aggressive response.

Most people would see it as fairly moral shooting terrorists who abduct children and wantonly murder people on behalf of their foreign paymaster. Otherwise, they'd likely face federal imprisonment in places like Guantanamo bay.

Mental age is something that's normally not seen as super important to people who kill terrorists.

Comment: Most people might approve killing terrorists, but in this case would they really regard these "fiends" as *terrorists* ? They resemble children and originate from the same community, many of their parents may still be alive. I wonder if this answer would connect to the opening scenario. It might happen if the "devil" is foreign, its identity is known and its role is known. But that would deprive the "fiends" of any character, they would become mindless soldiers, there is no ethics dilemma.

Comment: @Goodies most fathers and mothers would agree that their sons deserve death if they commit crimes like murder or rape, most fathers would have to stop themselves from actually kill their sons with their own hands.

Comment: The satanic panics of the 1980s were intense. People really don't like Satan, and while people would certainly try to preserve their own children, other people would be fine killing people who were working with a foreigner to kill or replace their children.

Comment: This answer is relevant if the Fiends are "over there" in another country. It is more a matter of PR than morality. It doesn't make sense to say whether most of us are in favour or against smart bombing paramilitary children, since we never met the children, controlled the bomb, saw the explosion et cetera.

Comment: If however the fiends are in my community, and I have the choice to either lie to the police about my cousin who became a fiend last week, or turn him in. Then it makes sense to ask about my morality.

Comment: @User89947 I find that very hard to believe. I have never seen or even heard a story of a father killing their son, with their bare hands, in return for a violent crime.

Answer (score 2):

**Morally right is a weird way to put it**

If those effects are not reversible, it gets progressively easier to make a decision as their minds decay to this sort of corruption.

When a good person loses himself to "madness" and starts to represent a hazard to other peoples lives, the reasonable thing to do would be to lock them up, if that is not in question and they represent **immediate** danger to someone, killing them is the sensible thing to do, as they are no longer themselves and do not have memories of their past lives, if you look at it this way you are saving a life (of the person who is in danger) and setting another free(by killing the feind).

Answer (score 2):

## Is it Moral to Kill Elves on sight?

Elves (the [Sidhe](https://www.libraryireland.com/AncientLegendsSuperstitions/Sidhe-Race.php)) are widely understood to be "soulless" child-swapping supernatural beings. So while they are not specifically evil, they are associated with those evil actions. People make judgements about supernatural beings based on all sorts of criteria. Are those criteria true or false? Are there exceptions? Are some elves evil and others good?

Can your fiends do good? If one fiend decides that he will use his new-found powers for good (or perhaps he was planning to so so from the beginning) then it is proof that all fiends are not doomed, soulless creatures to be treated as demons.

Then further, there is the question of if it is acceptable to punish people based on their perceived inherent guilt, rather than punishing them for crimes they actually committed. A bigot could say all whites are murderers who should be killed for their collective crimes (and yes, I've hear people say this). Another could say all blacks should be slaves because they're just made that way (which was a prevailing view for centuries). Jews were collectively killed because of their perceived responsibility for all the problems in the world.

The same argument can be made for people of faiths you disagree with. People chose to be Scientologists, and I disagree with them, but not matter how much I disagree with them , I don't think they can be killed for their "wrong" choices. People have killed others for being Catholic, Protestant, Muslim, Hindu, and almost every other faith that can be thought of.

**So I do not think it is morally justified to kill all of an entire group based on a shared identity (even one you deeply disagree with).**

If you want to defeat evil, being more evil than your rivals is no way to show the world you're better than them.

Comment: I think this depends on what the elves do to the human children. If a human couple secretly swaps their baby with yours and raises the child normally, that's a serious crime, but not a death penalty offense in most places. If they drop their baby in your child's crib and then murder your baby, that will have some people suggesting execution even in countries without the death penalty. A group of non-humans regularly murdering human babies being proven to exist would find itself on the fast track to becoming an endangered species no matter what the law says.

Answer (score 2):

Let's assume a worst case scenario for fiend control. A country with no capital punishment and extremely high standards regarding killing in self defense, plus the whole changeling thing is considered a rumor.

Despite being ageless, these fiends do have human identities. So, the 15 year old juvenile delinquents with ever more violent criminal records start ending up with adult sized prison sentences.

What this accidentally creates is a captive population of fiends who aren't aging properly. A handful of exceptionally youthful 30-40 year olds in the wild can lie about there ages and even be explained away as "must have great genes" if one or two are matched up to their real identities by their fingerprints. An ever growing number in prisons will set off alarm bell that eventually will be heard at the highest levels of the government.

Even then, it can't turn into a "shoot teenage hooligans on site" order. Plenty of normal teenagers get busted for bad actions and manage to turn into functional adults later.

Chances are that immortality, even of devilish origin, would require some cellular level changes (telomeres not shortening comes to mind). If there is a way to sort bad vs fiendish, I would expect the verified fiends in a country with firm opposition to the death penalty could expect to be imprisoned for life. This would continue until holding an ever growing population of immortal prisoners requires more extreme methods. Yes, I already know that even hinting at such a thing makes me a terrible person, but in the face of a situation like this, it's going to end up being on the table of options sooner or later.

The only method to avoid this very horrible final solution is to find a way to cure the fiends or at least control their fiendishness.

And there is still the whole changeling situation to deal with. If those are better able to blend in to society, they could do things like altering positive vs negative results on fiend tests, working in fiend holding camps and sabotaging the security systems, and working their way up in the government where they could provide all sorts of creative "solutions" that make things worse.